# Why is the luarocks makefile failing to find my lua interpreter?

Tags: build, lua, makefile, luarocks

I'm trying to install luarocks to a custom location.  I've downloaded the latest tarball (v2.3.0) and run the following `./configure` command:

```
# OPENRESTY_PREFIX is set to /opt/openresty
./configure --prefix=$OPENRESTY_PREFIX \
            --with-lua=$OPENRESTY_PREFIX/luajit \
            --with-lua-include=$OPENRESTY_PREFIX/luajit/include \
            --with-lua-lib=$OPENRESTY_PREFIX/lualib
```

This produces the following error:

```
Checking Lua interpreter... lua not found (looked in =/opt/openresty/luajit/bin)
You may want to use the flag --with-lua or --with-lua-bin. See --help.

configure failed.
```

I first checked that `/opt/openresty/luajit/bin/lua` properly invoked the interpreter, which is the case.  I then inspected the contents of `/opt/openresty/luajit/bin` and found the following:

```
$ ls -al /opt/openresty/luajit/bin/
total 2860
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jan  9 14:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root    4096 Jan  9 14:05 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      44 Jan  9 14:05 lua -> /opt/openresty/luajit/bin/luajit-2.1.0-beta1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Jan  9 14:05 luajit -> luajit-2.1.0-beta1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2918392 Jan  9 14:05 luajit-2.1.0-beta1
```

As we can see, `lua` and `luajit` are symlinks that point to `luajit-2.1.0-beta1`.  I figured that `make` was perhaps struggling with the symlinks, so I tried running the original command with `--lua-suffix=jit-2.1.0-beta1`

I obtain a similar error message, so it appears that even when pointing to the "real" file, `make` is getting tripped up:

```
Checking Lua interpreter... luajit-2.1.0-beta1 not found (looked in =/opt/openresty/luajit/bin)
You may want to use the flag --with-lua or --with-lua-bin. See --help.

configure failed.
```

I'm clearly missing something fundamental, here.  What am I doing incorrectly?

## Supplementary Information

### Build target

I'm building against a `debian:jessie` docker image.  Here is the corresponding `Dockerfile`, in case it helps reveal the directory structure.

```
FROM debian:jessie

# derived from https://github.com/ficusio/openresty/blob/master/debian/Dockerfile

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl perl make build-essential procps libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libpcre3-dev libssl-dev

ENV CFLAGS '-O2'
ENV OPENRESTY_VERSION 1.9.7.1
ENV OPENRESTY_PREFIX /opt/openresty
ENV NGINX_PREFIX /opt/openresty/nginx
ENV VAR_PREFIX /var/nginx

# NginX prefix is automatically set by OpenResty to $OPENRESTY_PREFIX/nginx
# look for $ngx_prefix in https://github.com/openresty/ngx_openresty/blob/master/util/configure

RUN cd /tmp \
    && echo "==> Downloading OpenResty..." \
    && curl -sSL http://openresty.org/download/ngx_openresty-${OPENRESTY_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar -xvz \
    && echo "==> Configuring OpenResty..." \
    && cd ngx_openresty-* \
    && readonly NPROC=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || 1) \
    && echo "using upto $NPROC threads" \
    && ./configure \
    --prefix=$OPENRESTY_PREFIX \
    --http-client-body-temp-path=$VAR_PREFIX/client_body_temp \
    --http-proxy-temp-path=$VAR_PREFIX/proxy_temp \
    --http-log-path=$VAR_PREFIX/access.log \
    --error-log-path=$VAR_PREFIX/error.log \
    --pid-path=$VAR_PREFIX/nginx.pid \
    --lock-path=$VAR_PREFIX/nginx.lock \
    --with-luajit \
    --with-pcre-jit \
    --with-ipv6 \
    --with-http_ssl_module \
    --without-http_scgi_module \
    -j${NPROC} \
    && echo "==> Building OpenResty..." \
    && make -j${NPROC} \
    && echo "==> Installing OpenResty..." \
    && make install \
    && echo "==> Finishing..." \
    && ln -sf $NGINX_PREFIX/sbin/nginx /usr/local/bin/nginx \
    && ln -sf $NGINX_PREFIX/sbin/nginx /usr/local/bin/openresty \
    && ln -sf $OPENRESTY_PREFIX/bin/resty /usr/local/bin/resty \
    && ln -sf $OPENRESTY_PREFIX/luajit/bin/luajit-* $OPENRESTY_PREFIX/luajit/bin/lua \
    && ln -sf $OPENRESTY_PREFIX/luajit/bin/luajit-* /usr/local/bin/lua \
    && apt-get remove -y make build-essential \
    && rm -rf /tmp/ngx_openresty* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR $NGINX_PREFIX

# Example contents for the `nginx` directory can be found at:
# https://github.com/ficusio/openresty/tree/master/_example/nginx
ONBUILD RUN rm -rf conf/* html/*
ONBUILD COPY nginx $NGINX_PREFIX

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off; error_log /dev/stderr info;"]
```

Comment: What is the output of: `[ -x /opt/openresty/luajit/bin/lua ] ; echo $?` EDIT: nevermind, found the issue, answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `OPENRESTY_PREFIX` is not set to `/opt/openresty` but to `=/opt/openresty`. This is given away by the error message:

```
Checking Lua interpreter... lua not found (looked in =/opt/openresty/luajit/bin)
```

which is generated by the following line:

```
echo "lua$LUA_SUFFIX not found (looked in $LUA_BINDIR)"
```

You just have to find out where that extraneous `=` sign comes from now. It could also be from the `configure` command line, e.g.:

```
--with-lua==$OPENRESTY_PREFIX/luajit
```

Comment: `echo $OPENRESTY_PREFIX`  prints `/opt/openresty`.  Aso, the `ENV` command in the Dockefile doesn't have the `=` token anywhere in the statement, so I don't think the extraneous `=` sign is coming from the environment.  This is a good lead to follow, but I'm not sure what else could be responsible ...

Comment: actually, I stand corrected.  I replaced the environment variable with the path literal and the problem was fixed.  Somehow `--some-flag=$ENV_VAR/some/path` doesn't work, whereas `--some-flag=/some/path` does.  Any suggestions for maxing environment variables coexist with the `=` token?